# Approximate the following determinant

Tags: real-analysis, determinant

Let $f(x)$ be a smooth odd function $f(x) = -f(-x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then I am interested in approximating the following determinant for small $\epsilon$.
$$D=\det_{1 \leq i , j \leq n} f((x_i - x_j)\epsilon)$$
My conjecture is that $$D \sim C_f \left( 1 + O(\epsilon)\right)\epsilon^{n(n-1)} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(x_i - x_j)^2$$ (as $\epsilon \to 0$) where $C_f$ is some constant that depends only on the function $f$. However I am struggling to show this. It is clear that $D$ is a symmetric function of $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and vanishes when $x_i = x_j$ for $i \neq j$. This implies that $D = g(\epsilon x_1, \dots, \epsilon x_n) \epsilon^{n(n-1)} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(x_i - x_j)^2$ for some smooth function $g$. The difficulty is showing that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}g(\epsilon x_1, \dots, \epsilon x_n) \neq 0$. I would also like to compute $C_f$ (I expect it will be related to the Taylor/Maclaurin coefficients of $f$).

EDIT: of course, $n$ should be even. The determinant is $0$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: What does determinant mean on the reals?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This is just an ordinary $n \times n$ determinant from linear algebra. I have said the $x_i$ are real variables for concreteness but they could be complex.

Comment: You write $g(\epsilon x)$, but there's no $x$ in the definition of $D$, only $x_1,\dots x_n$ ... what exactly is meant?

Comment: I was using the notation $x  = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$. I will edit the original question.